# Помогите составить css selector выбора одного из детей

Tags: css, css-selectors

Не получатся составить `css selector`

Есть `div` контейнер с дочерними элементами:

```html
<div className="slick">
  <div className="slick-slide slick-cloned" />
  <div className="slick-slide slick-cloned" />
  <div className="slick-slide slick-cloned" />
  <div className="slick-slide slick-active slick-current" /> 
  /* ! */<div className="slick-slide slick-active" /> /* НЕ МОГУ ДОБРАТЬСЯ ДО ЭТОГО ЭЛЕМЕНТА (следующий после slick-current) */
  <div className="slick-slide slick-active" />
  <div className="slick-slide" />
  <div className="slick-slide" />
</div>
```

Нужно выбрать сл. элемент, который идет за классом ***`slick-current`*** (и закрасить его фон красным цветом).

При том что ***`slick-current`*** и следующие за ним ***`slick-active`*** смешаются в позиции списка по направлению вниз.

Потом все повторяется.

P.S. Этот html генерируется компонентом [react-slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/)
P.S.S. Спасибо ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.slick-slide {
  min-height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.slick-current {
  background-color: green;
}

.slick-current + .slick-slide {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slick">
    <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active slick-current">Текущий</div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Its true!